# pgfplot not showing first data point loaded from external file

Tags: pgfplots

This is my first time using `pgfplot`, I'm trying to get data plotted from a file but for some reason the very first data point is not plotted.

Here's the data that is written to an external txt file (is this formatted incorrectly?):

```
Frequency   dB
0.0000000   -2.065753   
43.066406   -0.715069   
86.132813   -0.133365   
129.199219  -0.137862   
172.265625  -0.097547   
215.332031  -0.028865   
258.398438  -0.004819   
301.464844  -0.029135   
344.531250  -0.047452   
387.597656  -0.029668   
430.664063  -0.003602   
473.730469  -0.004216   
516.796875  -0.023170   
559.863281  -0.028084   
602.929688  -0.012229   
645.996094  0.000157
```

And the code that follows:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[xmode=log, xmin=-1, xmax=20000, ymin=-1, ymax=0.5, xlabel={Frequency}, ylabel={dB}]
\addplot table
    {external_file.txt};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

The result is this:

[image]

The very first coordinate, `(0.0000000,-2.065753)`, does not show. I'm not expecting to see a point, but just a line that goes off the screen. When I set the first point to `(0.0000001,-2.065753)`, it shows a line going off the screen, so from that it seems like the first point is being detected, and the line can be drawn as a result.

Comment: I think the issue is really that you are not seeing the line that connects `(0, -2)` and `(43,-0.7)`.  The issue is that the slope/intercept of the line is poorly/not defined.

Comment: Ah, I see, perhaps because I'm using a logscale and log(0)=-Inf, that's why 0.000001 works.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it has been solved by a comment below the question.